# What does it mean by scanf(" "); with only a space between the double quotes?

Tags: c, scanf

I have read code like below:

```
scanf("%s", str);
scanf(" ");
```

I guess the second line of the code is just to swallow the last \n character when inputting the string of the first line. But I just do not understand how this argument works.

Comment: It might be a trick to consume all white spaces up to (an including) an end of line in order to be able to use a `fgets` after a `scanf`. The downside is that it will eat all empty lines following the current line, which may or not be expected...

Comment: `scanf("%s", str)` is not a sensible thing to do... how big is `str`? and what happens if (when) `scanf()` writes past the end of `str`? Prefer something that is tightly bounded.

Comment: @user3386109 But the target here is to consume the whitespace characters that came AFTER not before the string. So does the second scanf work in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scanf(" ")` will consume as much whitespace as it can, including a newline left over after a string is consumed with `%s`.  However, the value of `str` is unaffected by this; `scanf("%s", str)` will leave out the trailing whitespace, whether or not you subsequently consume that whitespace with `scanf(" ")`.

So, `scanf(" ")` on its own is kind of pointless.  It might make sense if you followed it up with a whitespace-sensitive read, like this:

```
scanf("%s", str);
scanf(" ");
scanf("%c", c);
```

But then, you could have just written:

```
scanf("%s", str);
scanf(" %c", c); // Note the leading space.
```

And this only matters for `%c`, `%n`, `%[`, and *unformatted* input functions like `fgets()`.  All other `scanf()` format specifiers automatically skip leading whitespace.